# I have two styles one is tailwind and the other is style.css but they dont show well

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm having two styles but they are not showing well what can I do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the style declaration is after the tailwind and try to edit your post with more details if that didn't work.